# How do I delete/move old forms/documents from my document library in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am supporting a Sharepoint 2007 site with a couple workflows associated with some document libraries. The customer wants files that have not been modified in 3 months moved to a specific document library automatically. Is there a way to do with with Sharepoint tools automatically, or do I have to create some kind of custom web part (if thats even possible for this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to use the built in information management policies framework. Per list or document library you can setup scheduled checkpoints per item. At these checkpoints you can then "retire" an item, delete it or else archive it off to an archive list. Also, you can simply call a predefined SharePoint workflow to determine what should happen.

A typical example would be an information management policy that checks the list items weekly and calls a custom workflow upon then. You could then associate a workflow that checks the current item's modified date, check whether it's greater than 3 months and then simply move the item.

Have a look into the Share records management [here](http://sharepointrecordsmanagement.com/tag/sharepoint-expiration/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a timer job. You'd set it up to run every day, e.g. The job would use CAML query to get old documents from the doclib and perform the move operation.

--- Ferda

Comment: This is also a good idea but requires development when they information management policy framework is already provided for this purpose. +1